# Should OpenACC pragmas or runtime routines be preferred?

Tags: c++, pragma, openacc

OpenACC has some pragmas and runtime routines, which can be used to basically achieve the same thing.

For example, there is `#pragma acc wait` and `acc_wait()` or `#pragma acc update [...]` and `acc_update_[...]()`.

I started to mostly use the runtime routines in my C++ code.

Is there a difference? Should I prefer one over the other or is it just a matter of style and personal preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the pragma's are preferred since they will be ignored by other compilers and when compiling without OpenACC enabled.  The runtime API calls would need to be guarded by a macro, like "#ifdef _OPENACC" to maintain portability.

Though, if you don't mind adding the macro guards or loosing portability, then it's mostly a matter of style.  Functionally, they are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, the point about pragmas being ignored by other compilers is an important one.